# Recovery mode asks for a password OS X 10.8.2

Tags: password, recovery

When I tried booting into recovery mode (<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) during boot up, there's a field asking for a password. I do not know this password.

[image: Password Screen]

I am using a late-2009 21.5" iMac.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: So, is there someone who set the firmware password on that machine?  Ask them... Or you are the only user, and somehow did it yourself accidentally?

Comment: I faintly remember doing it ages ago but I guess I forgot it. The password was definitely one of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image, it looks like a Firmware password.

This bash script may be able to decrypt your firmware password, however it only works on a limited set of computers.

```
python -c "print ''.join(chr(int(c, 16) ^ 170) for c in '`sudo nvram security-password`'.split('%')[1:])"
```

[Source](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57521667-263/use-the-calculator-to-reveal-a-macs-firmware-password/)

Comment: Hey! Thanks very much for the help. I already decrypted the password and managed to get into recovery mode using the tutorial here: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57521667-263/use-the-calculator-to-reveal-a-macs-firmware-password/. Thanks again!

Comment: @moka No problem :D You do realise that was the same link that I put in my post ;)

Comment: Oh haha sorry, I didn't check the source link. Thanks again for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your mac is pre 2011 then removing a strip of ram and rebooting will clear the problem. I have done this with quite a few that I have installed new systems onto and it seems to work very well. Give it a try, what have you got to lose.